# How to suppress Details section based on value in database field

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to make a report suppression of Detail B segment based on a value from a database field.

I tried to set the variable and suppress based on value of variable but it only shows for one Detail B. Maybe increment of value is not working?
Current state:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz7mH.jpg

Expected output will be that if database field will be 6 that section Detail b will appear six times in report.
Expected state:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWryy.jpg

I am totally new in Crystal Reports so I prefer a simple solution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried a formula field?

Comment: Yes, but can you give me some example? Maybe i am using wrongly formula field.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Section and go to Section Expert and write the suppress formula by clicking the button on right side of Suppress option. [image: Please see the screenshot]